# How to get similar completion from coc as ycm?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-coc

I've been user of `YCM` for years now. Recently discovered `coc-vim` and trying it out.
Looks like it provides loads of additional features on top of what YCM has.

One thing that I can't figure out how to get to work is the default completion YCM had. E.g. when writing as bash script, YCM would automatically recommend completion suggestions while typing - e.g. function names.

```
nvim -version
NVIM v0.7.2
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
```

How to enable this in vim-coc? Any other recommendations for someone coming from YCM as for configuration or useful reading material?

Comment: Do you still have the problem? How can you help you further? If one of the answer solves your problem maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. I allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by removing items from vimrc line-by-line. Mine had two issues:

1. `set wildmode`
2. `set paste`

First interferes with command tab completion, and the other disables the autocompletion UI. After both settings were removed, coc-vim started behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

With `Coc` you have to install language support for the target language.

For `bash` one solution is to run the command:

```
:CocInstall coc-sh
```

It will install the [sh language server](https://github.com/josa42/coc-sh)

Comment: Did that. This is what I ran after installing coc: `nvim +'CocInstall -sync  coc-snippets coc-tsserver coc-json coc-html coc-css coc-pyright coc-sh' +qall`

Comment: Did you ran the `:CocInstall coc-sh` within Vim? What is the result? Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: Command above installs it within `neovim`, yes; screenshot of explicitly re-installing `coc-sh`: https://i.imgur.com/VevZiTf.jpg; relevant part from `:checkhealth`:  https://i.imgur.com/acYmJYT.jpg

Comment: Thanks. With this you should get the completion. I have tested that I gat at least the function name defined in the script. Can you five us an example of you expect and what you get?